# How can this user have an account on many sites but no network account?

Tags: bug, spam, network-profile, 404-not-found

[This spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13662643/user13662643) has about twenty accounts across the network, but their [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/18739004/user13662643) shows a 404 Page Not Found. What's going on here?

I often check the network profiles of users whose posts are identified as (potential) spam by [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/#whats-smokey) in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), to see if they have suspicious activities elsewhere in the network. That's why it's important that this works in edge cases too.

Comment: Looks like the deletion script broke halfway through; I think a fellow mod on SO tried to  nuke the account (with a 1 year suspension applied first) but deletion didn't complete; the display name was cleared on SO for example but not anywhere else. Perhaps that happened _while the spammer was creating other accounts_?

Comment: Even better: their user history log is _almost entirely empty_. The entries that are there are from _after_ the deletion attempt.

Comment: In SEDE that user doesn't exist: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1330123

Comment: Can someone else flag the posts on Area 51 Discussions? Does Smokey not monitor that?

Comment: @Laurel Smokey does monitor that, but sometimes it misses posts. Thanks for drawing my attention, I've reported them manually now.